# Impact of Stack Overflow Reputation on Potential Recruiter

Tags: discussion

I have been using stack-overflow since last 4-5 years. And have started trying to build the reputation for a while. However, I find this ask very time-consuming -  all the correct answers often don't get rewarded with points.

I have started wondering now whether building a good reputation on StackOverflow is really a worthwhile thing I am doing. Or should I spend my time sharpening my other skills themselves. Do recruiters, specifically for Software Developer position really look at SO reputation while making a decision?

If someone can share a positive experience of their good SO reputation on their SD recruitment, it would be really very helpful

PS: I am a ruby on rails developer and machine learning enthusiast.